Why does GNOME still display the default icon in the dock?
I've recently installed TeamSpeak 3 on my linux machine. I've created a .desktop file in /usr/share/applications/teamspeak.desktop with the following content:
Name=TeamSpeak 3
Comment=TeamSpeak 3 VoIP Communicator
Exec=/opt/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/ts3client_linux_amd64 %u
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Network;Application;
Icon=/opt/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/teamspeak-icon.png

When I search for the file in the launch menu, it displays the icon fine:

However, when I launch the application, the default icon is shown instead in the dock:

How can I fix this?

What WM_CLASS does xprop report for the program's window?

It says WM_CLASS(STRING) = "ts3client_linux_amd64", "TeamSpeak 3"

Modifying the .desktop file to include StartupWMClass=ts3client_linux_amd64 indeed fixed the issue for me. The full .desktop file now looks as follows:
[Desktop Entry]
Name=TeamSpeak 3
Comment=TeamSpeak 3 VoIP Communicator
Exec=/opt/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/ts3client_linux_amd64 %u
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Network;Application;
Icon=/opt/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/teamspeak-icon.png
StartupWMClass=ts3client_linux_amd64

